# Python 3.6 AttributeError: module 'statsmodels' has no attribute 'compat'

Tags: python

Totally new to Python. Saw no hits whatsoever on this error. Here's what I did, almost to the keystroke:

1. Clean install of Python 3.6.
2. pip install -U statsmodels
3. pip install scipy
4. pip install numpy
5. pip install statsmodels --upgrade
6. (In Python): import statsmodels.api as sm -> "AttributeError: module 'statsmodels' has no attribute 'compat'"

Any suggestions? I'm just trying to walk through a multi regression tutorial on https://towardsdatascience.com/simple-and-multiple-linear-regression-in-python-c928425168f9. Full traceback follows.

Thanks in advance.

```
>>> import statsmodels.api as sm
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\dataylor\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\api.py", line 35, in <module>
    from .stats import api as stats
  File "C:\Users\dataylor\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\stats\api.py", line 65, in <module>
    from .mediation import Mediation
  File "C:\Users\dataylor\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\stats\mediation.py", line 22, in <module>
    import statsmodels.compat.pandas as pdc  # pragma: no cover
AttributeError: module 'statsmodels' has no attribute 'compat'
```

Comment: It doesn't look as though `statsmodels` is properly installed. It may be worth uninstalling it with `pip uninstall statsmodels` and then installing again with `pip install statsmodels`

Comment: I think that was it! Thanks!

Comment: If the answer below solved your problem, please consider clicking the tick next to the post. This let's the community know your question has been answered.

Answer (score 17):

In my case, also using Jupyter Notebook, the solution was to use:

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
```

instead of

```
import statsmodels as sm
```

This is the recommended approach (as per [documentation](http://www.statsmodels.org/stable/index.html)), as statsmodels.api is the public access, and statsmodels (without api) might stop working. In my case, I used the GLM function.

Comment: Using `import statsmodels as sm` instead of `import statsmodels.api as sm` works for my case.

Answer (score 3):

Formulating @Will Kneeling's comment into an answer for users with a similar problem.

The `Statsmodels` package seems to have not installed properly. Try uninstalling and reinstalling the package, like so:

```
pip uninstall statsmodels 
pip install statsmodels
```

Answer (score 2):

In case you're working with `jupyter`, try to **restart the notebook server**.

Usually `pip install <package>` makes the package available without issues, but for `statsmodels` I kept getting the above mentioned error until I restarted the notebook server.