# probit, statsmodels : AttributeError: module 'statsmodels' has no attribute 'discrete'

Tags: python-3.x, statsmodels

I have already check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50607465/python-3-6-attributeerror-module-statsmodels-has-no-attribute-compat) post and uninstall and install again but I have still same problem.

```
import statsmodels

results = statsmodels.discrete.discrete_model.Probit(y, x)
print(results.summary())
```

and I get

```
    result_3 = statsmodels.discrete.discrete_model.Probit (y, x)
AttributeError: module 'statsmodels' has no attribute 'discrete'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Submodules are not automatically imported.

For example, you need to import discrete_model before you have it available

`statsmodels.discrete.discrete_model`

or use the `api` interface

See http://www.statsmodels.org/dev/api-structure.html for background and motivation for this.

Comment: thank you. I solved that problem to directly call Probit 

"from statsmodels.discrete.discrete_model import Probit"

Answer (score 0):

You could also import in this way

```
from statsmodel.api import Probit

model = Probit(y,x)
```

try this